# Why ValueContainer doesn't receive isFocused prop

Tags: react-select

I wish to override with custom ValueContainer, there is rendered the component in ValueContainer which style depends on if Select is focused. Why ValueContainer doesn't receive isFocused prop like Placeholder, for example,  receives

```
return (
  <SelectContainer
    {...commonProps}
    className={className}
    innerProps={{
      id: id,
      onKeyDown: this.onKeyDown,
    }}
    isDisabled={isDisabled}
    isFocused={isFocused}
  >
    {this.renderLiveRegion()}
    <Control
      {...commonProps}
      innerRef={this.getControlRef}
      innerProps={{
        onMouseDown: this.onControlMouseDown,
        onTouchEnd: this.onControlTouchEnd,
      }}
      isDisabled={isDisabled}
      isFocused={isFocused}
      menuIsOpen={menuIsOpen}
    >
      <ValueContainer {...commonProps} isDisabled={isDisabled}>
        {this.renderPlaceholderOrValue()}
        {this.renderInput()}
      </ValueContainer>
```

In the presented fragment render method of Select from Select.js You can see that isFocused variable is in scope and can be easily passed down.

Comment: I'm also encountering this issue! I can see that it does receive state but you just don't get the `isFocused` prop. Really annoying!

Answer (score 0):

If you want `isFocused` to be available in `ValueContainer`'s props, you have to pass it in as one:

```
<ValueContainer {...commonProps} isDisabled={isDisabled} isFocused={isFocused}>
  {this.renderPlaceholderOrValue()}
  {this.renderInput()}
</ValueContainer>
```

Comment: But... this fragment is a part of a react-select library, I would have to open Pull Request to introduce that change